# Label levels of a character variable in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to create a new variable with labels of a character variable in a preceding column such that 6 = "6) Hazardous", 5 = 5) Very unhealthy", 4 =  4) Unhealthy etc

I have tried other options but I keep getting NA's

```
data <- structure(list(Year = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021), Month = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 
6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12), Day = c(1, 17, 3, 
23, 12, 29, 14, 1, 18, 3, 20, 7, 23, 9, 26, 11, 28, 15, 31, 17, 
4, 21), Hour = c(2, 18, 10, 18, 10, 2, 18, 10, 2, 18, 10, 2, 
18, 10, 2, 18, 10, 2, 18, 16, 8, 0), AQI = c(407, 356, 278, 107, 
154, 215, 100, 171, 69, 167, 68, 135, 76, 128, 76, 57, 151, 168, 
157, 179, 264, 256), AQI_desc = c("6) Hazardous", "6) Hazardous", 
"5) Very unhealthy", "3) Unhealth for sens. groups", "4) Unhealthy", 
"5) Very unhealthy", "2) Moderate", "4) Unhealthy", "2) Moderate", 
"4) Unhealthy", "2) Moderate", "3) Unhealth for sens. groups", 
"2) Moderate", "3) Unhealth for sens. groups", "2) Moderate", 
"2) Moderate", "4) Unhealthy", "4) Unhealthy", "4) Unhealthy", 
"4) Unhealthy", "5) Very unhealthy", "5) Very unhealthy")), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

char_to_num <- list("Good " = 1, "Moderate" = 2, "Unhealth for sens. groups" = 3,"Unhealthy  " = 4, "Very unhealthy" = 5, "Hazardous" = 6)
```

Comment: I do not quite understand the question. Looks like the OP is trying to create an `ordered factor`?

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: just do `data$AQI_desc_new <- factor(data$AQI_desc)` The new column has the levels ordered

Comment: @Onyambu write it as an answer!  /s

Comment: Or do you need to get the numbering? ie `data$AQI_desc_new <- readr::parse_number(data$AQI_desc)`

Comment: @Mark I am not sure what OP wants. whether to convert the character to factors, or to get the integers associated with the levels. etc

Comment: @Onyambu you can always give them a few options (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the numbering is in the data itself, you can extract it using `parse_number`:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(AQI_desc_new = parse_number(AQI_desc))

# A tibble: 22 × 7
    Year Month   Day  Hour   AQI AQI_desc                     AQI_desc_new
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                               <dbl>
 1  2021     1     1     2   407 6) Hazardous                            6
 2  2021     1    17    18   356 6) Hazardous                            6
 3  2021     2     3    10   278 5) Very unhealthy                       5
 4  2021     2    23    18   107 3) Unhealth for sens. groups            3
 5  2021     3    12    10   154 4) Unhealthy                            4
 6  2021     3    29     2   215 5) Very unhealthy                       5
 7  2021     4    14    18   100 2) Moderate                             2
 8  2021     5     1    10   171 4) Unhealthy                            4
 9  2021     5    18     2    69 2) Moderate                             2
10  2021     6     3    18   167 4) Unhealthy                            4
```